# unity Shader returns a NULL when using Shader.Find

Tags: unity-game-engine

As stated [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/check-box-to-force-include-in-build-for-shaders.14111/) I am not the only one finding the following problem:

Shader.Find returns a Null.

In the link above they gave a solution by creating something(?) in the Resource Folder, but I am not sure I understand. First, is this necessary for all cases? (meaning Shader.Find does not work by itself?)
Second, what should I add? An unlit shader?? a material? 
Very confused here

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I could solve the problem finally by doing the following:

First, go to unity editor: Edit->Project Settings-> Graphics
Then in the inspector where it says "Always Included Shaders" add "Unlit/Texture"

Then change my Shader.Find code to read `Shader.Find("Unlit/Texture");`

With this it does not return null anymore

Answer (score 2):

You should add your shaders to any of the scene objects otherwise they work only in editor.
Add your shader to Resource Folder or you can create new one.

**In Resource Folder**

RightClick -> Create -> Material 
When you select the material you will see the shader field in inspector,choose the suitable one for you.

For example: 
in my script;

```
var newMtl = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard (Specular setup)")) { name = materialName };
```

So I added the material and select Standard (Specular setup) as the shader.