# Shader.Find("Standart") returns null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46033156/unity-shader-returns-a-null-when-using-shader-find) question, but this solution did not help me.

In custom editor window I set Standart shader to some materials. Materials were loaded from folders in project:

```
        List<Material> materials = new List<Material>();
        string[] _matPaths = FindAssetPathsWithExtension(".mat", folderWithMaterials);
        foreach (string materialPath in _matPaths)
        {
            Material mat = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(materialPath, typeof(Material)) as Material;
            if (mat != null) { materials.Add(mat); }
        }
        string filePath = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < materials.Count; i++)
        {
            materials[i].shader = Shader.Find("Standart");
            Debug.Log(materials[i].shader);
        }
```

Graphics settings screenshot:

[image]

Debug log:
Hidden/InternalErrorShader (UnityEngine.Shader)

Comment: It's `StandarD` with `D` and not `StandarT`

Answer (score 1):

I'm 120% sure it's not called standarT (standard maybe?). If you wanna know what a shader's name is, you'll have to look at the source. You can grab the source for Unity's built-in shaders from the downloads section of their website.

Comment: It is standard. OP even posted an image of it.

Comment: I don't ever trust built-in stuff to actually be what they look like. If it's called standard and sits at the topmost level of the shader menu, that doesn't mean it isn't called "unity_built_in_shaders_blah_blah_yada_yada/standard".

Comment: Why people posting answers like this and why it's getting upvoted, it won't help anyone beside OP.

Comment: I thought we were all answering OP's question here...

Comment: Because it is the answer to OP problem - it's just a typo.

Comment: And also it is off topic, cause simple typo is off topic in SO.

Comment: @SeM It will be closed, but what is wrong to point the problem to OP?

Comment: @Reniuz Don't get me wrong, nothing wrong with question/problem, just [answer or comment on such questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question).

Comment: Yeah, but I also wanted to point out where OP can get the shader sources, hence the answer.